# Are there women without glasses?

Tags: fallout-shelter

One thing I noticed in Fallout Shelter is that all women in the game seem to wear glasses. Some male dwellers dont have glasses, but every single woman I have had in my vault so far have worn glasses. I have no legendary character yet, so I dont know if that includes women without glasses.

So are there women without glasses in the game at all or did they not design them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Yes.

[image]

Just wait, you'll get some eventually.

Comment: +1 for those haunting smiles while they frantically extinguish the room. It's what Fallout shelter is about.

Comment: Ok, ty. I had a vault with 60 dwellers (had to delete it because of a bug) and now have a new vault with 25, but no woman without glasses so far. So i guess it was just bad luck.

Comment: @Studoku Haha, thanks, I tried to find a funny pic ^^

Comment: k, now have a vault with 110 dwellers and 2 survival vaults with 20. No women without glasses so far, they seem to be very rare...